# StreamWriter and Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes produces different results

Tags: c#, utf-8

Why does encoding a string to byte[] with `StreamWriter` and `UTF8.GetBytes` produce different results?:

```
string value = "myTestValue";

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
byte[] streamedData;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    streamWriter.Write(value);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

//false
data.SequenceEqual(streamedData);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's all about the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and the way `Encoding.GetBytes()` is implemented.

The static object `Encoding.UTF8` is initialized to include BOM as you can see in

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
```

As a result StreamWriter correctly writes it to the given Stream object (with BOM). However `Encoding.GetBytes()` never emits BOM; even if you construct the UTF8Encoding object to do so:

```
byte[] withoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(value);
byte[] withBom = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(value);

// true
withoutBom.SequenceEqual(withBom);
```

If you want the StreamWriter to encode without BOM you can initialize it like:

```
new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false)
```

This way both binaries will be equal.